# Add "help" column in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, filter, web-parts

I have a page viewer as main window showing an external page as we are not allowed to change that page I need to open a separate column inside sharepoint with Help-information. I would preferably want to show all categories of information in list and when I click one of the categories it expands to show the information below. How can this be done in Shrarepoint and if it needs to much work how would you solve it instead in an effective way? Maybe use filtering in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a custom list and have it group by the Help Category, does this help?

When you group it allows you to do the expand\collapse.

Comment: You can add the list as a web part itself